# Problems with enabling multimedia-, volume- and brightness-keys in the i3 window manager with Macbook Air

Tags: keyboard, macintosh, i3

I'm not able to make the multimedia-, volume- and brightness-keys to work in the i3 wm on my Macbook Air from 2015.
I have inserted the code which is supposed to enable the buttons however it doesn't work. Reloaded the config settings and tried restarting the computer. The following is the code I use:

**Pulse Audio controls**

```
bindsym XF86AudioRaiseVolume exec pactl set-sink-volume @DEFAULT_SINK@ +2%; exec pactl set-sink-mute @DEFAULT_SINK@ 0
bindsym XF86AudioLowerVolume exec pactl set-sink-volume @DEFAULT_SINK@ -2%; exec pactl set-sink-mute @DEFAULT_SINK@ 0
bindsym XF86AudioMute exec pactl set-sink-mute @DEFAULT_SINK@ toggle
```

**Media player controls**

```
bindsym XF86AudioPlay exec playerctl play-pause
bindsym XF86AudioNext exec playerctl next
bindsym XF86AudioPrev exec playerctl previous
```

**Sreen brightness controls**

```
bindsym XF86MonBrightnessUp exec xbacklight -inc 20 # increase screen brightness
bindsym XF86MonBrightnessDown exec xbacklight -dec 20 # decrease screen brightness
```

which I found on [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/794403/media-keys-on-macbook-pro-and-i3) question

Is it possible that the multimedia keys have a different name on certain Macbooks?

I have also tried [this](https://faq.i3wm.org/question/3747/enabling-multimedia-keys.1.html)

Perhaps there is a significant place I have to place the code?

***Edit 1***

I can see the command line reacting when I press the buttons

***Edit 2***

When executing the xbacklight command in the prompt I get the following output:

```
% xbacklight -inc 20
No outputs have backlight property
```

***Edit 3***

I've now solved for the volume keys with the following rows

```
bindsym XF86AudioRaiseVolume exec amixer -D pulse sset Master 5%+
bindsym XF86AudioLowerVolume exec amixer -D pulse sset Master 5%-
bindsym XF86AudioMute exec amixer -D pulse set Master 1+ toggle
```

***Edit 4***

Found great info here: https://faq.i3wm.org/question/3747/enabling-multimedia-keys.1.html

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but an answer may help out others. I ran into an issue upon a fresh installation of `i3wm` on my laptop where, for whatever reason, my `XF86MonBrightnessUp/Down` keys weren't being registered (I checked with `xev`). What I ended up doing is creating `acpi` actions and events which corresponded to the keys being pressed.

The following are the actions/events I defined in `/etc/acpi/actions` and `/etc/acpi/events`, respectively:

#### Actions

*/etc/acpi/actions/bl-down.sh*

```
#!/bin/sh

bl_device=/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
echo $(($(cat $bl_device)-1)) | sudo tee $bl_device
```

*/etc/acpi/actions/bl-up.sh*

```
#!/bin/sh

bl_device=/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
echo $(($(cat $bl_device)+1)) | sudo tee $bl_device
```

#### Events

*/etc/acpi/events/bl-down*

```
event=video/brightnessdown BRTDN 00000087 00000000
action=/etc/acpi/actions/bl-down.sh
```

*/etc/acpi/events/bl-up*

```
event=video/brightnessup BRTUP 00000086 00000000
action=/etc/acpi/actions/bl-up.sh
```

You can verify your brightnessup/down acpi event codes by using `acpi_listen` in your terminal and then pressing the relevant key combination (e.g., for me, it's Fn + Down Arrow for brightness down).

Finally, don't forget to restart `acpid` with `sudo /etc/init.d/acpid reload`

**Note:** Your backlight device may be defined in a different location than `/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0` - that's just where mine happened to be. Do some poking around.